# Error with virtualenv after having installed python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, debian, virtualenv

I've just installed python 2.7 from source for my Debian Squeeze. But now, when I use virtualenv, for this specific python version, I have this error:

```
~/ENV$ virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python2.7 --no-site-packages --distribute script_prod
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/virtualenv", line 2, in <module>
    import virtualenv
ImportError: No module named virtualenv
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I've found out that I need to install virtualenv with python2.7 in order to make it works!